# Understanding roles of 'Element' and 'TypeMirror' in `UnmodifiableCollection`

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

If we consider any generic type, for example, the below given code taken from `java.util.Collections`,

```
static class UnmodifiableCollection<E> implements Collection<E>, Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1820017752578914078L;

        final Collection<? extends E> c;

        UnmodifiableCollection(Collection<? extends E> c) {
            if (c==null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
            this.c = c;
        }

        public int size()                   {return c.size();}
        public boolean isEmpty()            {return c.isEmpty();}
        public boolean contains(Object o)   {return c.contains(o);}
        public Object[] toArray()           {return c.toArray();}
        public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)       {return c.toArray(a);}
        public String toString()            {return c.toString();}

        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
           ...
        }

        public boolean add(E e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        public boolean remove(Object o) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> coll) {
            return c.containsAll(coll);
        }
        public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> coll) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> coll) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> coll) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        public void clear() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter) {
             throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        } 
    }
```

I would like to understand,

1)
How to identify `TypeElement`, `ExecutableElement`, `VariableElement`, `AnnotationMirror` roles of `javax.lang.model.element` package for the above code?

2)
How to identify `DeclaredType`, `WildcardType`, `ExecutableType`, `MirrorType` roles of `javax.lang.model.type` package for the above code?

3) Is `AnnotationMirror` a mirror based reflection system as mentioned in this [paper](http://www.bracha.org/mirrors.pdf)?

*Note: `element` & `type` package is meta level facility, which is different from traditional reflection system(`Object.getClass()` method or `Type.class` literal)*

Comment: What do these have to do with `UnmodifiableCollection`? Do you have a specific problem with this class, or does your question apply to any generic type?

Comment: @Clashsoft I just took this as an example. My question applies to any generic type. I saw you partially answered

Comment: Fair enough, I already guessed that.

Answer (score 0):

The `*Type` and `AnnotationMirror` classes are all part of the `javax.lang.model.element` package, which is used when building custom annotation processors. The base class for this is [`javax.annotation.processing.Processor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html), which is a good place to start looking for help.

Essentially, all of these types represent nodes in the Abstract Syntax Tree of a compiler that calls your annotation processor. They are read-only, which means that you can only add custom errors, but cannot modify the source code.

Comment: Can you please answer my 3 questions?

Comment: I don't really understand how you want to 'identify' these - it depends on how you 'walk' the Abstract Syntax Tree that the compiler passes to your annotation processor in the `process` and `getCompletions` methods.

An `AnnotationMirror` simply represents an immutable view of an annotation in the AST.

Comment: 1) What does 2 arguments of `process()` method i.e., `Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations` & `RoundEnvironment roundEnv` represent?  ## 2) What does argument of `init()` method i.e., `ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv` represent?

Comment: The `RoundEnvironment` describes the current annotation processing "run", while the `ProcessingEnvironment` sort of represents the compiler, allowing you to access useful data such as a `Messager` (which lets you print error messages) or the current source version. A `TypeElement` represents a type, such as `String` or `List<Integer>`.

Comment: What is the meaning of "current annotation processing 'run' "? I did not get you.

Comment: I recommend you read the documentation for these methods and classes. Otherwise, there is not much I can help you with. Also, I am not sure why you are asking this question and what you need all the information for.